# Select files from system's local drive using cypress

Tags: cypress, automated-testing

How to select files from a local computer and upload to the website using cypress?

Comment: Any one can let me know that how we can upload the simple image file into cypress code.

Answer (score 2):

Cypress does not support file upload out of the box. However there are several workaround that might or might not work for your particular case. You can observe the [official cypress github discussion](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/170) where people suggest their workarounds for your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Cypress does not currently support native browser events such as filepicker, however, it is on their roadmap. [native browser events](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/311) The workaround is to add files to your fixture folder and then to create a custom command like

```
Cypress.Commands.add(
    'dropFile', {
        prevSubject: false
    }, (fileName) => {
        Cypress.log({
            name: 'dropFile',
        })
        return cy
            .fixture(fileName, 'base64')
            .then(Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob)
            .then(blob => {
                // instantiate File from `application` window, not cypress window
                return cy.window().then(win => {
                    const file = new win.File([blob], fileName)
                    const dataTransfer = new win.DataTransfer()
                    dataTransfer.items.add(file)

                    return cy.document().trigger('drop', {
                        dataTransfer,
                    })
                })
            })
    }
)
```

Then in your tests, you can do something like:

```
it('Uploads a CSV', () => {
    cy.document().trigger('dragenter')
    // you don't need to use cy.document() that is where my event listener is. 
   //you could use cy.get('element').trigger('dragenter')
    cy.dropFile('test.csv')
})
```

Or you can use the plugin published and listed on the Cypress plugins page:
[Cypress.io Plugin Page](https://docs.cypress.io/plugins/)
 Direct link here
[drag and drop repo](https://github.com/4teamwork/cypress-drag-drop)

Answer (score 1):

You can select out one of the fixtures present in project and pass it to your file unput via:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload

After that you need to submit a form (or start uploading in any other way), but that's details related to your specific case.